# can't print out rest of the key values after removing one of the key value from an instance of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator

I have a instance of LinkedHashMap, using a if-else statement, I want to remove one of the key value from LinkedHashMap and print out the rest. However, instead of printing out the rest of the keys, the IDE is printing out a lot of information that I dont understand. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Map<String, Integer> msi1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

msi1.put("hello", 1);
msi1.put("world", 2);
msi1.put("morning", 3);

for (Iterator<String> it = msi1.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    if (it.next().equals("world")) {
        it.remove();
    } else {
        System.out.println(it);
    }
}

java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator@15db9742
java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator@15db9742
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were correct to use an iterator if you intend to remove elements from a `Map` while iterating.  However, you were attempting to print out the iterator object directly, which doesn't make sense.  In the code snippet below, I instead print out the key and value of a non-matching entry.

```
Map<String, Integer> msi1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

msi1.put("hello", 1);
msi1.put("world", 2);
msi1.put("morning", 3);

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = msi1.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = it.next();
    if (entry.getKey().equals("world")) {
        it.remove();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Found entry: " + entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! now i understood what's going on! will tick as soon as SO allows me to.